# Why does dns_get_record() PHP function returns empty array?

Tags: php, arrays, dns-get-record

I had a script in one of my websites that fetched DNS Records using `dns_get_record()` PHP function. But it's about 2 week that this function returns an empty array. I wrote a test script like below:

```
<?php
$result = dns_get_record("php.net");
if (count($result)) {
    print_r($result);
} else {
    echo 'Empty Array';
}
?>
```

It works well on my local machine, but when I test it on my server, it returns *Empty Array* as result.
What's the matter friends ?

Comment: It's more likely that $result is false rather than an empty array which would indicate it failed.

Comment: Your server is DNS blind whereas client is not

Comment: @AsConfused may you give me a solution? I had not such problem before

Comment: print $result . are you getting array there ?

Comment: On same server? Describe the server os

Comment: @DeepKakkar it prints `Array` as result.

Comment: @AsConfused yes the same server. It's CentOS 6

Answer (score 0):

Check DNS ports are open on the server, it requires TCP/UDP port 53.

You can check that your server can make outbound DNS queries by typing the following

`dig exmaple.com` and see if you get the expected response.

Check server has DNS servers set and then check the firewall as previously suggested.

Lastly, worth check PHP versions on each machine?

Comment: `dig php.net` returns appropriate result. Also port 53 is open in firewall. PHP version is 5.3 on my local machine and 5.4 on my server.

Answer (score 0):

Clients need dns and dhcp or hard coded fill in the blanks.

Servers often sit blind to anything just responding to their ip addr directed traffic

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue when project was running inside docker container.

To fix this we used [Net_DNS2](https://github.com/mikepultz/netdns2) instead of native `dns_get_record`, with direct specification of which DNS server should be used.

```php
$dnsResolver = new Net_DNS2_Resolver([
    'nameservers' => ['8.8.8.8']
]);
$dnsResolver->query('php.net', 'NS');
```